# Do action until condition is met

Tags: ruby, arrays

I feel like this should be really easy and I'm just running into a wall.

I need to loop through an array until a condition is met. For example:

```
count = 0    
array = ["","","test","demo"]
```

I want to loop through this array incrementing count by 1 until the first non-empty value is found. So I want the index value of `"test"`, but when `"test"` is reached I want to stop the loop.

Also, as a side note, how can I just find the index of the first non-empty value in an array? I want to know both methods as they both have potential application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have both :)

This finds you the index of the first non-empty string:

```
array = ["","","test","demo"]
array.index {|str| !str.empty?}
#=> 2
```

You can update count in the `{|str| !str.empty?}`-block if you like, because `Array#index` loops from start to end through the array.

FYI: The `index` method is an alias of `find_index`

Comment: ouch ! you were faster :)

Comment: only by a few seconds ;)

Answer (score 1):

better use :

```
   first_non_empty_index = array.index{ |string| !string.empty? }
```

Answer (score 0):

*do/while*:

```
 begin
   puts arr[count]
   count+=1
 end while(arr[count].empty?)

puts count #2
puts arr[count] #test
```

Comment: eeeewwww. totally non idiomatic ruby

Comment: @m-x Ruby support lots of styles: O(O)P, Functional etc. Which such freedom comes responsibility, so if you want to comment on that, say something meaningful(for example: it's slower, you can not use X with it etc.)not spam like: I don't like it because it's not like X.

Comment: To clarify : Ruby DOES allow such constructs, but if you stick to these I think you're missing the point of the language. Ruby is all about expressiveness, so writing idiomatic code is important in this regard. Moreover, your code style introduces an unnecessary variable in the scope (count). that said, YMMV, apologies for the offense, that was not my intention

Comment: @m-x as for `count`, OP created himself/herself that variable. He/she want to store somewhere the *last index of the first non-empty value*, so in this case, it is necessary. And begin/end/while construct is like *do/while* from C. It looks "ok". That being said, it's not about "sticking" but being able to choice from variety of ways. To be honest I don't remember when I used this construction, but, I'm glad that ruby let me use it. And, in my opinion, that is what ruby is about, about "freedom to choice"(even it is not "the best" way).  ps. it's ok